# Android AppCompat dependency in custom library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-library

I just created a new library, [Powerful Image View](https://github.com/stefanosiano/PowerfulImageView/).
My library is a custom AppCompatImageView, so I need the appcompat-v7 library. And here comes the question:

How should I add it to my library?
Should I use 'compile', or 'provided' and let the user add the library to its own dependencies?
And how should i handle different versions of the libraries used, since i'm not depending on a specific version?

I added to the library's gradle file this line:

```
provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

I'd like to know your thoughts about this :)

Comment: you should at least explain the downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use 'compile', or 'provided' and let the user add the library to its own dependencies?

I would use `compile` and make sure that the developer using your library understands that your library relies upon `appcompat-v7`, as that in turn places lots of other requirements (e.g., using `AppCompatActivity`, using `Theme.AppCompat`).

> And how should i handle different versions of the libraries used, since i'm not depending on a specific version?

Well, you are requiring some version. `AppCompatImageView` does not exist in all versions of `appcompat-v7`. I recommend depending upon a concrete version (i.e., not `+`), ideally the latest-and-greatest version.

Comment: I see what you mean, but this also means that if the user uses a specific old version of the appcompat library, for any reason, he wouldn't be able to use it.  
And what about  
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+' ?

Comment: @StefanoSiano: "this also means that if the user uses a specific old version of the appcompat library, for any reason, he wouldn't be able to use it" -- the developer can direct Gradle to use the old version. "And what about compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+' " -- I have been steering away from `+` in general. You do not really know if your code will work with arbitrary future versions of `appcompat-v7` without modification, and the developer can choose to use an older or newer `appcompat-v7` anyway.